# Django+SharePlum and Rich Text Fields in SharePoint

Tags: python, django, sharepoint

Using Python with Django and accessing my SharePoint list via SharePlum.

In SharePoint the description field is Rich Text. When I bring that into my template file using Django it is still showing tags. For example:

```
<div class="ExternalClass5E185857E6A14259838D47F8D5A086FF">test</div>
```

Is there any way to render this with no tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. I went into SharePoint List Settings on Office 365 and changed it from Enhanced Rich Text to just Rich Text and it is showing properly now in my web app.

That was a good enough answer for my needs.